# 1px margin between two vertically laid out divs in Chrome (please read details)

Tags: html, google-chrome, margin

In Chrome browser on Nexus 7 and on HTC Android I can see a 1px margin between the top and bottom divs. On my Nexus 5 and on desktop it does not appear. If I use Chrome Dev Tools and switch on emulation mode I can see the white line. I can resolve the problem by adding a negative -1px margin, and a 1px padding to compensate, however, I'm trying to understand why this is occurring in the first place.

---

***The QUESTION: Can anyone explain why this is occurring i.e. what CSS rules are being used?***

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test margins</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .top {
            background-color: black;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .bottom {
            background-color: black;
            height: 50px;
            /*margin-top: -1px;*/ /* Potential fix I don't want to use. */
            /*padding-bottom: 1px;*/
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="top">
</div>
<div class="bottom">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screen shot of problem]

Comment: This is most likely one of many rendering quirks that so commonly plague mobile browsers.

Comment: Wait - "If I use Chrome Dev Tools and switch on emulation mode" I'm not entirely familiar with Chrome's dev tools but is this on the desktop, and if so, what specifically is emulated? If it's the device that's emulated, then my original comment applies. Otherwise, I got nothin'.

Comment: Maybe a quirk, but I am looking for explanation as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this because of rounding error of non-integer pixel density on these devices (1 CSS pixel maps to 1.25 or 1.33 device pixels)? If so, setting something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">` (3 FullHD device pixels per CSS pixel or 2 device pixel per CSS pixel for 1280x720 screens) should help.

Comment: Didn't solve it, but it helped me with another issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding border-box

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for workaround, but I'm looking for an explanation as to why this is happening as asked in original question.

Comment: This isn't a workaround. It is the DOM box model. Read up on the box model if you would like to see the specification.